# Should a user be able to list and see all their own questions that have been deleted, regardless of reputations?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

If I am correct, a **regular** user  is only allowed to list and see their  questions  that were deleted in the last 60 days, but **not all** their questions that have been deleted.
By "regular", I mean reputations under a high threshold (10k?).

Putting a reputation threshold is not only unnecessary but also discriminatory in nature. (Not to mention that it is very difficult for regular users to   accumulate enough reputations,  under the current toxic and harassment-encouraging  environment across the stack exchange network.)
Can I request that any user  should   be able to list and see **all** their own questions that have been deleted, **regardless of their reputations**?

Thanks.

p.s.  My reputations here have gained me the privilege, so I made the request for all  the regular accounts here and across the stack exchange network.

Comment: FYI only, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/307535 was status-declined in ~2010 if I'm reading the timeline correctly. Several subsequent bounties have been placed.

Comment: Is there some reputation threshold involved? How can high rep users see their deleted questions? As far as I know, everyone can see their deleted questions if they have a link to them, but there is no way of seeing a list of all your deleted questions.

Comment: @terdon https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3Ayes+is%3Aq?

Comment: Thanks @muru, I thought that was a mod-only thing.

Comment: Idiotically, in the profile page, the link is only to "recently deleted questions", whatever my rep is, so a user needs to know to search for them manually...

Comment: @Tim, that's a system-wide misfeature, not something that anyone can help on unix.meta.SE. And based on Jeff's link, probably not something that any user anywhere on SE can help, so I'd suggest just trying to live with it for now. But if you do decide to bring it up on meta.SE directly, I'd suggest dropping that note about toxicity and encouraging harassment, it won't help in getting any changes implemented.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks.   I am not able to post there.  My online account has been  complaining lately on some issues, though I don't like myself complaining and myself in real life rarely complain.